# How to combine two columns into one base on conditions in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am new to Excel. This might be really basic...Please help

```
Column1 Column2
A         B
C         D
E
F
G
```

The rule is if Column1 and Column2 are both not blank, get the values of Column2.
so the new columns will be:

```
Column3
B
D
E
F
G
```

Thanks!

Comment: `=If(Trim(A2)="",B2,A2)` in C2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In resultant column, you can use the following formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),A1,B1)
```